# What is wrong with my 2D Array Gaussian Blur function in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, image-processing, blur

I am making a simple Gaussian blur function for a 2D array that is supposed to represent an image. The function just prints out the array values at the end (no actual image processing going on here). I was pretty sure that I had implemented everything correct, but the values I am getting for (N=3, sigma=1.5) are much lower than expected based on this calculator: http://dev.theomader.com/gaussian-kernel-calculator/

I am following this equation:

[image]

```
void gaussian_filter(int N, double sigma) {
  
  double k[N][N];
  for(int i=0; i<N; i++) { //Initialize kernal to 0
    for(int j=0; j<N; j++) {
      k[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
   
  double sum = 0.0; //There is an issue somewhere in this block of code
  int change = (N/2);
  double r, s = change * sigma * sigma;
  for (int x = -change; x <= change; x++) {
    for(int y = -change; y <= change; y++) {
      r = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
      k[x + change][y + change] = (exp(-(r*r)/s))/(M_PI * s);
      sum += k[x + change][y + change];
    }
  }
  
  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) { //Normalize
    for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
      k[i][j] /= sum;
    }
  }
  
  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) { //Print out array
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
      cout<<k[i][j]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
  }    
}
```

Here is the expected output for N=3 and Sigma=1.5
[image]

Here is the current broken output for N=3 and Sigma=1.5
[image]

Comment: Not sure why you have `s = change * sigma * sigma` (`change` will be `1` for `N==3`) when the formula uses 2σ²

Comment: Good question. You are a bit shy of a [mre], but it looks like the information needed is in the question. watch out for `double k[N][N];`. That's a variable length array, a non-standard extension in C++ (but perfectly legal in many C implementations) and a really good way to kill a stack. On Windows with the default 1MB stack an `N` of around 350 could result in you having a very bad day.

Comment: @user4581301 A Gaussian Blur Kernel of N=350 would be *very* unusual.

Comment: Especially when the asker specifies `N`=3. Not an issue here, but I can't help proselytizing.

Comment: A Gaussian with sigma=1.5 needs quite a bit more than 3 pixels. That’s not a Gaussian what you made or the website showed you. You need at least 7 or preferably 9 pixels to correctly represent that Gaussian. See [my blog post](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/695) for an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does `s` depend on `change`? I think you should do:

```
double r, s = 2 * sigma * sigma;
// instead of
// double r, s = change * sigma * sigma;
```

Comment: This is certainly much closer to the kernel OP is aiming for. It's not exactly the same but closer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo If you're thinking about the division by `M_PI * s` ... that shouldn't matter, as the matrix is normalized afterwards.

Comment: @AdrianMole I'm not thinking really :-) I just ran the code.

Comment: `double r, s = 2.0757 * sigma * sigma;` comes _really_ close. Can the real magic number be found by doing some calculation? Hmm, that number is in a google book about wavelets in jpg:s but that's probably just a coincidence.

Comment: Or, equally, by making `sigma=1.528`. :-) ... `sqrt(2.0757/2) * 1.5`

Comment: @AdrianMole :-) Gah, this is annoying.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you guys for helping out!

Comment: @AdrianMole: yes, indeed, that website computes a wider kernel than requested, see my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

[That website](http://dev.theomader.com/gaussian-kernel-calculator/) computes Gaussian kernels in an unorthodox manner:

> The weights are calculated by numerical integration of the continuous gaussian distribution over each discrete kernel tap.

That is, it samples a continuous Gaussian kernel that has been convolved with a uniform (“box”) filter of 1 pixel wide. The resulting Gaussian is wider than advertised. I advise against this method.

The proper way to create a Gaussian kernel is to just sample the Gaussian function at given integer locations, for example `x = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]`.

Do note that a 3-pixel kernel is not wide enough to represent a Gaussian. It is important to sample the tail of the curve, without it, the kernel doesn’t have the good properties of the Gaussian kernel. I recommend sampling up to 3 sigma to each side, leading to `2*ceil(3*sigma)+1` pixels. 2 sigma is the bare minimum, useful only when speed is more important than good results.

Do also note that the Gaussian is separable, you can apply two 1D kernels in succession, rather than a single 2D kernel. For the 9x9 kernel you get for sigma=1.5, this translates to 9+9=18 multiplications and additions, compared to 9x9=81 for the 2D kernel. This is a significant saving!